# SocketRocket calling an open connection

Tags: ios, objective-c, socketrocket

i currently have a socketrocket connection in my appdelegate.m

```
_webSocket = [[SRWebSocket alloc] initWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"ws://pinkfalcon.nl:12345/connectr"]]];
_webSocket.delegate = self;
[_webSocket open];
```

And the response to that

```
- (void)webSocketDidOpen:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket;
{
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    NSLog(@"Websocket Connected");
}
```

How can i request that part from another view. I can't seem to find a delegate function to open a current connection on socket rocket. I can't seem to find the logic of the delegate function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `_webSocket` ivar is made available as a (hopefully readonly) property of your `AppDelegate`, from elsewhere in your code you can check the socket's state as :

```
if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.webSocket.readyState == SR_OPEN) {}
```

The different states are enumerated [here](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket/blob/master/SocketRocket/SRWebSocket.h#L20). Better yet would be to encapsulate this sort of checks into methods like `- (BOOL)socketIsOpen` or `- (BOOL)socketIsClosed` in your `AppDelegate`.

Also, if you want the socket opening to trigger other actions of your applications, you might want to use something like `NSNotificationCenter`, so any parts of your app can be notified of when the socket is open, and when it is closed:

```
- (void)webSocketDidOpen:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket {
    // your existing code
    NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [center postNotificationName:@"myapp.websocket.open" object:webSocket];
}

- (void)webSocket:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket didCloseWithCode:(NSInteger)code
           reason:(NSString *)reason
         wasClean:(BOOL)wasClean; {

    // your code
    NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [center postNotificationName:@"myapp.websocket.close" 
                          object:webSocket
                        userInfo:@{
        @"code": @(code), 
        @"reason": reason, 
        @"clean": @(wasClean)
    }];
}
```

This would allow other parts of your app to do:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(socketDidOpen:)
                                             name:@"myapp.websocket.open"
                                           object:nil];
```

where `socketDidOpen:` would take a single `NSNotification*` argument.

As a general advice, though, you shouldn't wait for a websocket connection to be open before making your UIWindow key and visible, as that would make your user inapt to use your app if no connection is available. In the general case, connection setup should be managed in the background and be asynchronous with setting up your application UI.

Comment: You sir, did the job! I'm always trying to avoid the notificationcenter. Doesn't seem like a solid solution somehow. But it does the trick for now. Thanks mate.

Comment: In some cases I also try to avoid NSNotificationCenter by directly building methods for registering observers and notifying them, but you then need to maintain a list of observers, watch for retain cycles and  thread safety. In most cases, that's overkill :)

Comment: in my opinion notification center is a very bad practice. It's not really oop, I would use a delegate or block to notify whoever I want. NSNotificationCenter is a nightmare to debug in my opinion.

Comment: Blacky, this is not really about being OOP or not, but rather do you want the flexibility of having N receivers of that change of state (for which you need a decoupled mechanism like NSNotification), or only need exactly 1 receiver (which you can do using the delegate pattern). You can store callback blocks on the notifier side, but you need to be careful with references, and depending on your implementation, it may force a synchronicity that may not be desirable. NSNotification is quite solid and used by many many folks, including Apple.